# how to integrate Ionic App with Android widget(Java)?

Tags: java, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, android-appwidget

I have made App using Ionic Framework and Android Home Screen widget using Java(as we cannot create widget using ionic,i guess).
so now I want to use some data from my app to Widget.Is their any way to get this..?

1. i have used PouchDB in my App. is it possible to access same database in both.
2. is it a way to access same encrypted file from both.
3. is angular-storage same as shared preference in android.as i have stored some data using angular-storage.

Comment: Use cordova SQLitePlugin to access db's from both.

Comment: How would you deploy this setup as one app?